# Jquery if radio is checked find a children element and change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to code this fake masked radio button, when the user clicks or taps on the a li, this finds and checks the child checkbox and changes the css of an icon I have from opacity-0 to opacity-1, basically shows the icon, everything works fine, when clicking on the li this triggers the checkbox on each li, but the icon should go back to opacity-0 when the user selects any other option, been trying to find a solution for this with no luck. Hope someone can help. I have a http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/7kSb9/1/

This is the JS I am trying to make work:

```
        function selectingLocation(){
            $('.location-list li').bind("click tap",function() {

                $(this).find(':radio').attr('checked','checked');

        //        $(':radio').on("change",function(){

                    if ($(':radio').is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).find('label').children().css({"color":"red"});
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).find('label').children().css({"color":"white"});
                    }                                                            
          //     });

            });
        } selectingLocation();
```

Comment: Why don't you use proper HTML by having the label be for the input. That way if someone clicks on the label, it selects the input. Standard behavior. Then work from there to whatever you want instead of starting from relatively poor markup. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jg4WN/

Comment: Then you can build upon a solid base and add the more fancy features -- it is easier this way in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(':radio').is(':checked'))
```

That line will always be true. You are not checking the child radio button, just if there is any radio button is checked.

Try this:

```
function selectingLocation(){
    $('.location-list li').bind("click tap",function() {

        $(this).find(':radio').attr('checked','checked');
        $(".location-list li").find("label").children().css({"opacity":"0"});
        $(this).find("label").children().css({"opacity":"1"});

    });
} selectingLocation();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JDewzy/7kSb9/8/

Comment: Look to use `prop()` not `attr()` in most recent versions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code:

```
function selectingLocation(){
$('.location-list li').bind("click tap",function() {
  $('.location-list li label').children().css({"opacity":"0"});
  $(this).find(':radio').attr('checked','checked').end().find('label').children().css({"opacity":"1"});
});
} selectingLocation();
```

I agree with Cymen, you should use his method and go from there. But for the sake of answering your question, here you go.

Here it is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kSb9/12/